# Ascensor.js very basic implementation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I started this very small project in order to get familiar with Asensor.js but I cannot make it work.

In my project directory I have an html file (shown below) and 5 javascript files that are supposed to be the corresponding plugins (I copied and pasted raw code in these files). The javascript files are: JQuery, Ascensor.js, a migrate plugin, an easing plugin, and a scrollTo plugin.

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Ascensor</title></head>
<script src="http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
<body>



<!-- HTML -->


<nav id="navigationMap">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="ascensorLink ascensorLink1 ascensorLinkActive">floor1</a></li>
        <li><a class="ascensorLink ascensorLink2">floor2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="ascensorBuilding" style="position: absolute; width: 1436px; height: 100%;">

    <section class="ascensorFloor" id='ascensorFloor1' style="position: absolute; width: 1436px; height: 100%; left: 0px;">
        <p>floor 1 content here</p>
    </section>

    <section class="ascensorFloor" id='ascensorFloor2' style="position: absolute; width: 1436px; height: 100%; left: 1436px;">
        <p>floor 2 content here</p>
    </section>

</div>



<!-- ascensor.js -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ascensor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/migrate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollTo.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor();

</script>



<!-- CSS -->

<style type="text/css">
    #ascensorFloor1 {
        background: red;
    }
    #ascensorFloor2 {
        background: blue;
    }
</style>



</body>
</html>
```

When I open the html file in my browser all the static content is displayed but when I click on the navbar links, nothing moves.

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you copied and pasted in the absolute positioned elements after the js had run. try this instead

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Ascensor</title></head>
<script src="http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
<body>



<!-- HTML -->


<nav id="navigationMap">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="ascensorLink ascensorLink1"></a></li>
        <li><a class="ascensorLink ascensorLink2"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="ascensorBuilding">
    <section>
       <p>floor 1 content here</p>
    </section>

    <section>
       <p>floor 2 content here</p>
    </section>
</div>



<!-- ascensor.js -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ascensor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/migrate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollTo.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor();
});
</script>



<!-- CSS -->

<style type="text/css">
    #ascensorFloor1 {
        background: red;
    }
    #ascensorFloor2 {
        background: blue;
    }
</style>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I replaced my html with what you proposed and the result is the same except that I lose all the css properties. Maybe I am not clearly understanding your solution. Can you tell me more?

Comment: @blrsk I've modified the code to show the full html that you can copy and paste

Comment: Thanks! I just tried your code but I got the same result. I might have a problem with importing the js libraries properly. What do you think?

Comment: In order to import the libraries, I just went online, copied the raw code for each of them, made a js sub directory in my project, and pasted all of them in different .js files there. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Look i'm still having SERIOUS issues, implementing this script, but from what I understand that I'm missing scrollto.js, so I will do that later, but for you, you might want to add your options between the brackets in `$('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor();`...

Means that if you want to name your floors , you write the next line:

```
$('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({AscensorFloorName:"Home | Implementation | HTML | Jquery | CSS | Smartphone | End"});
```

I hope this helps a bit, try to study the code of the examples page in [the github page of Ascensor.js](https://github.com/kirkas/Ascensor.js/tree/master/examples)

Please also note, that I will try to fully comprehend the code and will write a blog post about it :)

Good Luck!